# Bing Map : Direction Module directionsUpdated event throws error. We can't find directions between one or more waypoints

Tags: bing-maps

Bing Map Direction Manager throwing error on directionsUpdated event.

When I try to draw a rout using known source and destination lat & long with address it doesn't draw route on the map but just show source and destination icon and throw following error.

Error: We can't find directions between one or more waypoints.

Response Code: 1

[image]

Below is LoadDirection method code.

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', (e) => {

  this.directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(this.detailMap);
  this.directionsManager.clearAll();
  // Set Route Mode to driving
  this.directionsManager.setRequestOptions({
    routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving,
    routeDraggable: false
  });

  this.directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
    drivingPolylineOptions: {
      strokeThickness: 3
    }
  });

  this.directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
    firstWaypointPushpinOptions: { visible: false },
    lastWaypointPushpinOptions: { visible: false },
    waypointPushpinOptions: { visible: false }
  });

  const waypoint1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
    address: '2115 Beall St, Houston, TX 77008, US',
    location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.8052803, -95.4181495), icon: ''
  });

  const waypoint2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
    address: '4231 Brightwood Dr, Houston, TX 77068, US',
    location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(30.00005, -95.50392)
  });

  this.directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint1);
  this.directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint2);


  // Add event handler to directions manager.
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.detailPathLayer.clear();

    const routeIndex = e.route[0].routeLegs[0].originalRouteIndex;
    const nextLocation = e.route[0].routePath[routeIndex + 1];
    const pinLocation = pin.getLocation();
    const nextCoord = this.CalculateNextCoord(pinLocation, nextLocation);

  });

  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.directionsManager, 'directionsError', function (e) {
    console.log('Error: ' + e.message + '\r\nResponse Code: ' + e.responseCode);
  });

  this.directionsManager.calculateDirections();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem finding a route between the two locations you provided. This standalone code below works fine, with directionsUpdated event arg printed in console (Note that you have set waypoint pushpins to invisible through render options):

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(<CREATE_YOUR_MAP>);

Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', (e) => {

  this.directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
  this.directionsManager.clearAll();
  // Set Route Mode to driving
  this.directionsManager.setRequestOptions({
    routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.driving,
    routeDraggable: false
  });

  this.directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
    drivingPolylineOptions: { strokeThickness: 3 },
    firstWaypointPushpinOptions: { visible: false },
    lastWaypointPushpinOptions: { visible: false },
    waypointPushpinOptions: { visible: false }
  });

  const waypoint1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
    address: '2115 Beall St, Houston, TX 77008, US',
    location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.8052803, -95.4181495), icon: ''
  });

  const waypoint2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({
    address: '4231 Brightwood Dr, Houston, TX 77068, US',
    location: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(30.00005, -95.50392)
  });

  this.directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint1);
  this.directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypoint2);

  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });

  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.directionsManager, 'directionsError', function (e) {
    console.log('Error: ' + e.message + '\r\nResponse Code: ' + e.responseCode);
  });

  this.directionsManager.calculateDirections();
});
```

Can you check if the error is indeed thrown between these two locations? Is everything happening in directionsUpdated handler intentional? (e.g. CalculateNextCoord perhaps?)

Comment: No. It's not going into directionUpdated event. Before that It throws error into directionError. For me also this is surprising. I checked the same in SDK It's working in my app only not working. I put this code in Angular 7 Web Element. And If I remove address from both waypoints it doesn't load route as well.

Comment: @J S, Did you try above example without passing address in waypoint ? Actually I'm calling bing map API for reverse Geocode and pass that adress here. But before I get address this code is getting executed and it gives blank address.